# pinpoint put_events from lambda function NotFoundException

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-amplify, aws-pinpoint

I have set up an AWS PinPoint project and I'm trying to test it by sending an event from a lambda function:

```
import boto3
import datetime
import time

client = boto3.client('pinpoint')
app_id = '1234abcd'
endpoint_id = 'test_endpoint'
address = 'test@test.com'

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    response = client.put_events(
        ApplicationId = app_id,
        EventsRequest={
            'BatchItem': {
                endpoint_id: {
                    'Endpoint': {
                        'ChannelType': 'EMAIL',
                        'Address': address,
                        'Attributes': {
                            'Cart': ['Hat'],
                            'Purchased': ['No']
                        }
                    },
                    'Events':{
                        'cart-event-2': {
                            'Attributes':{
                                'AddedToCart': 'Hat'
                            },
                            'EventType': 'AddToCartEvent',
                            'Metrics': {
                                'price': 29.95
                            },
                            'Timestamp': datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()).isoformat()
                        }
                    }
                }
            } 
        }
    )
    return response
```

But I am receiving an error that the resource cannot be found, even though I can see it in Pin Point console:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "An error occurred (NotFoundException) when calling the PutEvents operation: Resource not found",
  "errorType": "NotFoundException",
  "requestId": "xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 12, in lambda_handler\n    response = client.put_events(\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 391, in _api_call\n    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 719, in _make_api_call\n    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)\n"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was just in the wrong region on my AWS account. 
I created the AWS pinpoint project in one region but was trying to send events to the project from another AWS region, which was why I was getting the NotFoundException.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: edit. Hope its more clear.